# How can I put a custom control's class inside another custom control?

Tags: wpf, class, nested, custom-controls

Say I have coded a custom `Canvas` like this :

```
public class MyCustomControl : Canvas
    {
        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
        }
    }
```

And I need to put another custom coded (custom control) `Label` inside it and use the whole project as ONE custom control in ANOTHER project.

I did this :

```
public class MyCustomControl : Canvas
    {
        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
        }
       //My custom label
        public class MyLabel : Label
        {
            public MyLabel()
            {
                Content = "Hello!!";
                Width = 100;
                Height = 25;
                VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't get to see the `Label` inside the OTHER project. see the pic:
[image]
Since I'm creating a custom control in the first project, I have no visual reference (like XAML design window or anything else) to which I can depend on, basically by seeing that all the elements are correctly coded and visible.

First, I don't know whether or not it's the right approach to create nested custom controls.
And second, I don't know why the label isn't shown there. It might be because I must add it to the canvas. But I don't know the code to add the label to it's parent, which is the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your Label to Canvas:

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
    this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
    this.Children.Add(new MyLabel());
}
```

But in this case you don't need a custom Label:

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
    this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
    this.Children.Add(new Label{
        Content = "Hello!!",
        Width = 100,
        Height = 25,
        VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
    });
}
```

If you want to able to design your Canvas, add a UserControl to your first project.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Canvas Background="LightBlue">
        <Label Width="100" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            Hello!!
        </Label>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
Gotta go test it right now ;) EDIT: It worked ! Thanks a lot Lisp ;)